# SAPUI5 oData model v2 submitChanges. Not always able to retrieve created data. Why?

Tags: odata, sapui5

I'm creating oData using the createEntry() method of the oData model (v2),

Then, on submitChanges(), I'm retrievinvg the newly created data with this.getPageBlocks() below.

However, intermittently, this.getPageBlocks() does not return the newly created entry, meaning the data is not refreshed correctly for the end-user.

Why is that? At what point does submitChanges() execute? I'm guessing it's executing before the actual backend data has been created, which would explain why it's not there when I run this.getPageBlocks()

```
pageModel.createEntry("/PageBlocks", {
...
...
}


then....


pageModel.submitChanges({
success: function (oData) {
    this.getPageBlocks();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, after submitChanges your entry should get updated. If you want to get the newly created entry, you should do the following:

```js
    _createEntry() {
        const oModel = this.getView().getModel();

        this._oEntry = oModel.createEntry("/PageBlocks", {...})
    }


    onSubmitButtonPress() {
        const oModel = this.getView().getModel();

        oModel.submitChanges({
            success() {
                this._oEntry.getObject() // Will return the newly created entry
            }
        })
    }
```